# Can't connect to game servers but Internet works fine

Tags: wireless-networking

I just bought a new top-of-the-range computer, and assembled it myself. Yesterday, I was playing on games fine. However, I tried to play on the same games and it failed to connect - this is for every game I try.

I've disabled my router firewall, my anti virus and windows defender. Nothing in any of their logs have anything to do with blocking connections. I can go open games' launchers, I can do everything on websites, but as soon as I try to connect to a game's server, it doesn't work.

I have several other computers using the same internet connection that work fine on the same games, so it's not an issue with the router (although I have tried resetting it). I can only think it is something to do with my computer and/or its wireless adapter, but as it was working yesterday and I haven't changed anything I can't think of a problem.

There was a brief error message after I reset the router for my computer when I tried to load the internet (something about DNS), but it was only for 3 minutes or so and I'm not sure if any of my other computers had the same problem or not.

I hope I've provided enough details for someone to fix the problem, I'm completely stuck :(

Comment: Take a look in your hosts file (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) and and see if there are any entries other than the localhost entry.

Comment: I was about to try that when a download for another game finished and started working. Intrigued, I tried my first game - it worked. It's back to normal, although I've absolutely no idea why.

Comment: @Pig Head - This sounds like its a router configuration problem.  It sounds like you are forwarding the ports as you would expect.  the problem is you can only forward a port to a single address.  On a side note it could also be your wireless adapter check the settings.

Comment: can you ping the game server? which port is the game using? is it open?

Answer (score 1):

My son had a similar problem- solved when he discovered that Internet explorer had somehow gone into "offline mode". Try checking your I.E settings
Hope this helps